# Angular Module Federation Shared Module with Npm Alias

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, alias, angular-module-federation

I have two Angular 14 projects.  I'm using the `@angular-architects/module-federation` package to create a host and a remote.  The issue that I am encountering is that I need to share a library as a singleton, but that library is aliased in the `package.json` file.  It is not a local library, but rather is a library hosted in two different registries.

For instance, I have something like this in the `package.json` files in both projects:

```
"@myRegistry-1-namespace/ui": "npm:@myRegistry-2-namespace/ui@3.0.0",
```

And when trying to share it, I have something like this in my `webpack.config.js`:

```
'@myRegistry-1-namespace/ui': {
    singleton: true,
    strictVersion: true,
    requiredVersion: 'auto',
  },
```

When I attempt to run the host, I get the following error:

```
Unsatisfied version 3.0.0 from myproject-host of shared singleton module @myRegistry-1-namespace/ui (required =npm:@myRegistry-2-namespace/ui@3.0.0)
```

Does anyone know how to get it to recognize the fact that I have the correct versions installed in both projects?

If I set `requiredVersion` to `false`, the host will load, but the project breaks at runtime (I assume due to the library needing to be a singleton).  If I remove the alias in the `package.json` files, it also works.  However, I need the alias (due to our projects ability to only connect to one of the registries in environments other than my local machine).